# Angular 2 Hiding with conditionals

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am using `*ngIf` to conditionally show a block of code which works as I need it.

However I need to use `[hidden]` or `display:none` to actually hide the block in the dom. As I understand I can only provide `true` or `false` with `[hidden]`.

How can I conditionally hide this from the Dom using `[hidden]` or `[class]` ?

```
<div *ngIf="raid != -1;">
    <p>Need to display:none inside of this</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can set any condition inside *ngIf="condition" that return a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your hidden option within the tag:

```
<p [hidden]="true">Need to display:none inside of this</p>
```

And replace the true within the "" with your variable name

Or as such if you want to hide just a part of the text:

```
<p>some text <span [hidden]="true">this will be hidden (or not) </span>some more text</p>
```

Comment: you can use something like 

[style.display]="!isLoading ? 'block' : 'none'"